# Sort recycler view by length of textview

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I am looking for solution for below problem.

I have recycler view which contains couple of textviews, I need to sort it by the length of one of the textviews. The shortest length should be first. I was trying to find some similar problems but I could not find any.

Does anyone have some optimal way to do it?

Comment: You need to sort your list of `RecycleVview` for that.

Comment: sorting should be applied to the list of items not to the recyclerView or adapter.

Comment: you should to sort your list by length of content,not to sort recyclerview items

Comment: @KonstantinVolkov yes of course, I mean I have a list which put it to recycler view

Answer (score 0):

You will sort your `List` by using [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Below is the way.

```
adapter.setList(Collections.sort(adapter.getList(), new LengthComparator()););
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**LengthComparator.java**

```
public class LengthComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: `getList()` and `setList()` are methods in your Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who is looking for answer in **Kotlin**
your List should be used in bind of Your ViewHolder(Also in Java)

```
 inner class ViewHolder(var binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    {

        fun bind(step : Steps, handler: ItemClickHandler)
        {
            list?.sortedBy { steps -> itemView.title.length() }
            binding.setVariable(BR.steps,step)
            binding.executePendingBindings()

        }
    }
```

its Worked For me